# Presentation of summary log-transformed data aiming at easier interpretation

Tags: confidence-interval, data-transformation

I have a list of measurements that is not normal and need to be log-transformed so that parametric statistics can be applied (e.g. mean, CI).

I can calculate the mean and CI without problem when the data is transformed, but the way of interpreting the log-transformed value is not straightforward to my readers. (the CI for the object length is 1-5 log cm, people usually will ask what is log cm?)

I am tempted to revert the CI with transformed unit back to it original unit, but I wonder if this is the right way to do so, or if there can be other alternatives?

The R script below will explain my question fully:

```
library(epicalc)

# creation of sample data
set.seed(1)
sample.measurement <- 10^(rnorm(1000, mean=1, 0.5))

# plotting histogram for sample data, too skewed to use mean to summarize data, 
# need to log-transform it
hist(sample.measurement)
# plotting histogram for sample data, much better this time
hist(log(sample.measurement, base=10))

# the calculation below should be wrong, as it is not normal data
ci.numeric(sample.measurement)

# this one should be better, as the data is log-transformed and become normal, 
# but the value is difficult to interpret/comprehend
ci.numeric(log(sample.measurement, base=10))

# I wonder if the method below is appropriate, for the sake of easier interpretation 
# using the original units
10^ci.numeric(log(sample.measurement, base=10))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but pure computer code is not a question: for one thing, it makes your question inaccessible to anyone not conversant with the language and to anyone not familiar with this particular package. If the question can *only* be stated in code, it doesn't belong here--it should be moved to SO.  If it's on topic here, then please state your question in English.

Comment: Good edit. When you apply a nonlinear transformation to the data, the mean has a different interpretation. For instance, the (arithmetic) mean of the logarithms is the log of the *geometric* mean of the data. This is a fundamental reason why back-transformation does not work in general.  There are many ways out, depending on how much you are willing to assume about the underlying distribution and what parameter you are actually estimating.

Comment: @whuber: it is positive skewed data, and actually I want to compare the length between object A and object B. Or should I simply calculate the CI using t-distribution?